# AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not permitted on the default exchange

Tags: php, laravel-5, rabbitmq, worker

I have this application in `Laravel 5.5` with `PHP7.0`. I am using this package [vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq](https://github.com/vyuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/tree/v6.0.3)

for pushing and receiving jobs from RabbitMQ. Here is my config:

```
'worker' => [
            'driver' => 'rabbitmq',
            'factory_class' => \Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory::class,
            'host' => env('RABBITMQ_HOST'),
            'port' => env('RABBITMQ_PORT'),
            'vhost' => env('RABBITMQ_VHOST'),
            'login' => env('RABBITMQ_LOGIN'),
            'password' => env('RABBITMQ_PASSWORD'),
            'queue' => env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE') . ',' . env('RABBITMQ_PROCESSED_QUEUE'),
            'options' => [
                'exchange' => [
                    'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', null),
                    'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DECLARE', true),
                    'type' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_TYPE', \Interop\Amqp\AmqpTopic::TYPE_DIRECT),
                    'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_PASSIVE', false),
                    'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_DURABLE', true),
                    'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_AUTODELETE', false),
                    'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_ARGUMENTS'),
                ],
                'queue' => [
                    'name' => env('RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE_NAME', env('RABBITMQ_JOB_QUEUE') . ',' . env('RABBITMQ_PROCESSED_QUEUE')),
                    'declare' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE', true),
                    'bind' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DECLARE_BIND', true),
                    'passive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_PASSIVE', false),
                    'durable' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_DURABLE', true),
                    'exclusive' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_EXCLUSIVE', false),
                    'auto_delete' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_AUTODELETE', false),
                    'arguments' => env('RABBITMQ_QUEUE_ARGUMENTS'),
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Now as you can see in the `"queue"` index I have defined two queues. In the lower part of the config the index `"queue"` contains an array with `"name"` as having the same two queues. It works fine on my local `env` but on test server it throws this error:

> AMQP error while attempting pushRaw: ACCESS_REFUSED - operation not
> permitted on the default exchange

Now this is my requirement that the same worker is monitoring two queues. I have to do it. How can I achieve this? Any solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to name the queue on the test server?